# How to return different object from jest.spyOn based on function call parameters?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

Currently I have this code for unit testing

```
mockWindow = {
  document: {
    createElement: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(div),
    head: {
      appendChild: jest.fn(),
    },
    body: {
      appendChild: jest.fn(),

    },
    removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
  },
  addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  removeEventListener: jest.fn(),
};
jest.spyOn(window, 'open').mockReturnValue(mockWindow);
```

Now I am adding another call to `window.open` to my code base with a different parameter:

```
 window.open('', 'new_target', 'width=1000,height=500')
```

I want to be able to return a different value when the second `window.open` is called. Is there anyway  I can ask `spyOn` to return different values based on the parameters?

I tried `jest.spyOn(window, 'open', '', 'new_target')` but I get this error `Error:(47, 5) TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4.`. The third parameter is supposed to specify the access type (i.e. get vs set)

Comment: What happens if you use `.mockReturnValueOnce('x')` multiple times to return different values? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions.html#mock-return-values